# Plotting multiple columns of data frame with color map on the same graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter

I want to plot column number 0 vs all the other columns with a colour map. 
I have written in following with For loop. However, all the graphs appear separately and not on the same graph. Below, is the code I wrote,

```
csv_file1    = pd.read_csv(r'file path')
j            = [i for i in range(1,175)]
for i in j:
    csv_file1.plot.scatter(0,i,c=i,colormap='viridis')
    plt.hold()
```

How to get all the plot of the same graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pandas, you'll need to draw all the plot using the same `ax`. Supposing you want to use the first column as `x` and all the other columns as `y`, everything colored via the `y` value. You need to suppress the colorbar, as pandas wants to add an individual colorbar for each column.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

csv_file1 = pd.read_csv(r'file path')

ax = plt.gca()
columns = csv_file1.columns
for col in columns[1:]:
    csv_file1.plot.scatter(x=columns[0], y=col, c=col, colormap='viridis',
        ax=ax, colorbar=False)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, if you want to give each column its own color, you could calculate a list of colors (pandas seems to like them in a list of one color):

```py
colors = [[plt.cm.viridis(i / len(columns))] for i in range(len(columns) - 1)]
for col, color in zip(columns[1:], colors):
    csv_file1.plot.scatter(x=columns[0], y=col, c=color, ax=ax, colorbar=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Now I understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak for pandas.plot, but you can control when canvases are cleared by using `plt.scatter` and placing `plt.show()` outside the loop

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

csv_file1    = pd.read_csv(r'file path')
j            = csv_file.columns.tolist()
for i in j:
    plt.scatter(csv_file1.index,csv_file1[i],colormap='viridis')
plt.show()
```